# Why my function code doesn't add first call of solution when it returns? it adds all recursive function calls solutions but not first

Tags: recursion

I'm solving the question,
**Given an integer N. Calculate the sum of series 13 + 23 + 33 + 43 + … till N-th term.**

I write this code but it can't add the first recursive function call solution.

**Ex -**

**N = 5 and the Answer is 1^3+2^3+3^3+4^3+5^3=225.
but it gives me 224, it doesn't add the first 1, Is any changes required here?**

```
using namespace std;

long long calSum(long long i,long long n)
{
    int sum = 0;
    if (i > n)
        return 0;

    sum = pow(i,3);
    
    return sum + calSum(i + 1,n);
}

int main()
{

    int n;

    cin >> n;

    cout << calSum(1,n) <<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a debug line after the sum:
sum = pow(i,3);
printf("pow(%lld,3)=%f\n", i, pow(i,3));

Then compiled it, and ran with 5:

```
5
pow(1,3)=1.000000
pow(2,3)=8.000000
pow(3,3)=27.000000
pow(4,3)=64.000000
pow(5,3)=125.000000
225
```